# Xcode prompting to bridge swift with objective c when rebuilding model

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I've made changes to my Core Data models. I've selected Editor > Create NSManagedObjectContext Subclass. Clicked next, next, next. Now xcode is prompting for confirmation on "would you like to configure an Objective-C bridging header".

Last time I did this I had no problems (xcode 7, swift 2.3). It created the correct Swift files. I'm now using xcode 8, swift 3.
I have no Objective-C code in my project.

When I click "Dont create", xcode creates .h and .m files with Objective C code in it.

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Select model.xcdatamodeld on the left, then in the File Inspector pane (far right, icon looks like a new document icon). Change Code Generation to Swift, form Objective-C.